# How to convert to decimal when data is number but not convert when data is text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 r2.
There are 31 fields (D1-D31) as varchar and keep 2 format data as number and text such as 'SD' and '123.456'.

I use the command for Data Base Expert of Crystal Report like this.

```
select
  case
    when D1 in('SD') then d1
    when D1 is NULL then ''
    else convert(decimal(7,2),d1)
  end
  .
  .
  .
  case D2-D31
from Rec2019 where ID ='P0009'
```

It's show Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
How to fix it ? please..

Comment: You cannot have a decimal and a varchar value in one column. What are you trying to achieve? Round the value?

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* and has a *type* determined by the types of *all* of it's `THEN`/`ELSE` clauses and the [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). What are *you* expecting the type of your `CASE` expression to be? You have to pick *one* for all rows in the result set here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A column has one datatype so you cannot place DECIMAL and VARCHAR values inside same column. I think you want to round numeric-ish values. In that case you can use the following:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(d1) = 1 AND d1 NOT IN ('+', '-', '$') THEN CAST(CAST(d1 AS DECIMAL(7, 2)) AS VARCHAR(9))
    WHEN d1 IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE d1
END
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ef52bb0d13395895dde1ec73880f5f8e)

Comment: The LIKE pattern is very naive... it simply checks if the first character is a digit. You can use `ISNUMERIC(d1) = 1` but that returns 1 for `-`, `$` etc. Other: make sure the length of varchar = length of decimal + 1 + 1 (one for possible minus sign and 1 for `.` character).

Comment: Result of number is stilling show decimal 3 but i need decimal 2

Comment: What is the value that fails?

Comment: My data is '123.456', I need result is '123.45' ,but your code stilling show '123.456'

Answer (score 1):

Since ISNUMERIC had some small downsides, for instance with scientific notation of numbers, I would use TRY_CAST, like this: (note: SQLServer 2012+)

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ColA VARCHAR (10))
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('1'), ('A'), ('2');

SELECT *, TRY_CAST (ColA AS DECIMAL (4,2)) AS Numb 
FROM #T
```

Sidenote: One column has one data-type, you cannot combine datatypes in one column in SQL Server.

Comment: It's only available since SQL Server 2012, and the OP is using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You can see that he wants both values in same column, you'rs will NULL any non numeric value.

Comment: Both of you: Thanks for pointing that out, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For `SQL Server 2008`, you can check using `ISNUMERIC`, where as SQL Server 2012+ have `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST` to make it simple like following.

```
TRY_CONVERT(decimal(7,2), D1)
```

Comment: @SalmanA, i just come to know that it is available after 2012+. I will update the answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

To convert when the data is number, and not convert when the data is text, you can check the type with the isnumeric function.

```
select
  case when isnumeric(D1) then convert(decimal(7,2), D1) else null end as D1_asnumeric
from XXX
```